# Dynamically Loading Javascript HTML CSS vs Page Redirect

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect, dynamic

I'm currently working on a web app that requires very little latency on the client side. The Web App has three main parts (signIn, viewItems, checkout).

Currently the state of the code looks something like this.

signIn.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signIn.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    some HTML body....
</body>
<script>
    some javascript that appends stuff to the DOM and makes ajax calls
</script>
```

viewItems.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/viewItems.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    some HTML body....
</body>
<script>
    some javascript that appends stuff to the DOM and makes ajax calls
</script>
```

checkout.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/checkout.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    some HTML body....
</body>
<script>
    some javascript that appends stuff to the DOM and makes ajax calls
</script>
```

(init.js above does some checks such as is the user signed in, etc.)

As you can see, each file follows has a very similar format but has a different HTML, CSS and Javascript functionality associated with it. Each file also has init.js, which basically performs a check to see if the user has signed in (and other security checks).

After init.js has performed the checks, it will either redirect the user to either checkout, signIn or viewItems. To increase the speed of the web app, I was looking to eliminate the page redirects, so I thought of loading the javascript, html and css tied to the file dynamically. I came across this article which indicates that what I am trying to do is possible. :

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

The goal is for the code will then look something like this:

index.html pseudocode

```
<head>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    if(user == signedIn)
        load viewItems.html
        load viewItems.css
        load viewItems.js

    else if(user != signedIn)
        load signin.html
        load signin.css
        load signin.js
</script>
<body>
</body>
```

My main questions is that will doing it this way (moving away from the redirect) significantly increase the speed (as loading the items in the head tag and the init.js performing checks are only done once, as opposed to being loaded every time the user is redirected). Or is this a moot point, as the speed increase will be negligible, and I'm better of redirecting the user anyways.

Comment: whoops, yeah that was just meant to be pseudocode, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer because there's so many variables that affect your speed, but here's what I would do.

Depending on your time constraints, you can try both (redirect and dynamic loading) and set up a speed test to determine which one is faster (of course, you'll have to take into consideration the locations, computers, browsers, etc. of your primary users).

Also, consider minifying the javascript and css files to improve performance and merging the js and css into 2 files (it's faster to load a single large js file than 10 small js files). Basically, keep the files separate for coding (makes it easier) and merge them into a single new file when you deploy the website.

Just search on Google: there are plenty of tools out there to help test speed and shrink/merge your js and css files.